# ¿Cómo colocar foco a un control de un grupo de controles con la misma clase?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy recorriendo un grupo de controles que tienen la misma clase por medio de la función `.foreach()` de JQuery; necesito poder colocar el foco a uno de estos controles de acuerdo del index que ocupe.

Valoraría mucho sus respuestas, Gracias!

Comment: tienes que publicar tu codigo para poderte ayudar de manera correcta y no jugar a la adivinanza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar

```js
var inputs = jQuery(".input").toArray();

inputs.forEach(function(inp){
  if(jQuery(inp).data('focus') === 2){
    jQuery(inp).focus();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" data-focus="1">
<input type="text" class="input" data-focus="2">
<input type="text" class="input" data-focus="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar algo como esto dentro del foreach:

```
if(/*condicion para detectar si es el control al que le quieres hacer foco*/){
    $(this).focus();
}
```